# Dereferencing object array pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this small question about dereferencing arrays. I have a method in class like this

```
T* foo()
{
 // create specific array of objects in here
 return (array)
}

foo2()
{
  myNewArray = *foo();
  // exactly the same algorithm as in foo to create checkArray
  cout << sizeof(myNewArray) << sizeof(checkArray) << endl;
}
```

I get two different results, but I expect them to be the same?

Ok, so the additional information about the code:

```
vec4* getGridAttr()
{
        float xval = -0.5;
        float yval = -0.75;
        float xval2 = -0.5;
        float yval2 = -0.75;
        vec4 pointsGrid[100];

        for (int i=0;i<42;i++)
        {

          //Draw horizontal lines
          if (i % 2 == 0) pointsGrid[i] = vec4(xval, yval, 0.0,1);
          else if (i % 2 != 0) {
             pointsGrid[i] = vec4((xval+0.75), yval, 0.0,1);
             yval += 0.075;
             }
        }
        for (int j=42;j<64;j++)
        {

          //Draw horizontal lines
          if (j % 2 != 0)
          {
              pointsGrid[j] = vec4(xval2, yval2, 0.0,1);
              xval2 += 0.075;

          }
          else if (j % 2 == 0) {
             pointsGrid[j] = vec4(xval2, -yval2, 0.0,1);

             }

        }
        return (pointsGrid);
}
```

and in my other method, i have this:

```
void display( void )
{

vec4 points1[100];
//code here populates points1 exactly the same as in getGridAttributes, 

cout << "points1 : " << sizeof(points1) << "   " << "  pointsFromGridAttr : " << sizeof(*getGridAttr()) << endl;
}
```

The output is points1 : 1600 pointsFromGridAttr 16

Comment: How is `myNewArray` defined?  How is `checkArray` defined?  How is the array created?  Pseudo-code won't help us figure out what's going on; what is your real code?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code I can't be sure of this, but if you have something like this:

```
T* arr1 = makeArray();
T arr2[n];
```

Then `arr1` and `arr2` would have different sizes.  Specifically, `arr1` is a pointer, so its size is the size of a pointer, while `arr2` is an array, and its size will be the size of a `T` object times the number of objects in the array.

Although arrays and pointers in C++ can be interchanged in some contexts, they really are different types.  `T*` and `T [n]` are different types with different sizes.  Once an array decays to a pointer, it loses its size information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to compare the *length* of the arrays. The length of a C array should be calculated as `sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof(type_of_array_elements)` or `sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof(one_element)`, not just as `sizeof(array_variable)`. For details see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c).

Try this:

```
cout << sizeof(myNewArray) / sizeof(myNewArray[0]) << ", " << sizeof(checkArray) / sizeof(checkArray[0]) << endl;
```